# Rescale a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Lets assume that $A_1$ a function with maximal value $M$ and minimal value $m$ with $M \neq m $

How can i find the transformation that maps this function to $A_2$ with $N$ as new maximal value and $0$ as new minimal value?

Comment: Isn't $A_2(x) = N \frac{A_1(x) - m}{M - m}$ enough?

Comment: I don't know if the minimal value that must be $0$ affects and this transformation does not exist?

Comment: just check what the formula gives when $A_1 = m$ and $A_1 = M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we want to "move" the function "down" by $m$, so we take $A_1-m$. Now the maximal value is $M-m$, and we want to make it $N$ so we multiply by $\frac{N}{M-m}$, and so: $$A_2 = \frac{N(A_1-m)}{M-m}$$

Note that $M-m>0$ because $M>m$. The minimal value is when $A_1$ attains its minimal value which is $m$, so we have $N(m-m)=0$ in the nominator and so the minimal value is $0$, and similarly one shows that the maximal value is $N$.

Comment: i think you mean $ A_2 = { N(A_1-m)\over M-m} $ or i am wrong?

Comment: @xkrpz: Yes, that was a typo. Thanks!